# Force the order of recipes with Chef

Tags: chef-infra

The situation is that the installation of the standard cookbook `chef-provisioning` will fail because of the fact that the Nokogiri gem will fail to compile with native extensions. This is the case for Ubuntu and CentOS. A bug for sure - now I'm trying to find a workaround.

The compile fail is caused by missing packages. On Ubuntu package `liblzma-dev` and `zlib1g-dev`.

To install missing packages I created a separate cookbook `fix-missing`. My run list is `fix-missing` and then `chef-provisioning`.

It seems that Chef ignores the run list order. Unexpected, I don't fully understand this yet, but in any case, if not using the run list, how should this be done?

My workaround is to first create run list with only `fix-missing`, run that and then update the run list to include `chef-provisioning`.

run list with both will always fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're facing is due to `chef-gem` installing the gem at compile time (to allow using the gem in recipe just after).

If you need to install packages before, the you're on the right path using a recipe before in the run list (chef respect the order you give), but you have to enforce this package installation at [compile time](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#run-in-compile-phase) too.

```
package "libzma-dev" do
 action :nothing
end.run_action(:install)
```